# Can I export my SQL code (queries) to my computer as a .sql document?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I was asked to analyze a dataset in BigQuery (never used it until now) and I need to export my code as .sql documents. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Big Query lets you save the queries on the cloud so you can use them later, as you may have noticed.

But if you really want to store them as files in your computer, you can always copy the code, paste them in a notepad and them save it as .sql, which can then be imported in platforms like PostgreSQL, etc.

Big Query doesn't allow you to load .sql files, though.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I'd end up having to manually copy and paste. Unfortunately I don't have notepad because I'm using a Mac so I'll have to figure something out.